# How do I get the text of a button to appear when I have clicked it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make it so text fades in when I click a button. Any help is massively appreciated!

```js
$(".btnClick").click(function(event) {
  var x = $(this).text();
  if (x == "PowerApps") {
    $(this).parent(".show-details").find('.show-me').fadeIn(500);
  } else {
    $(this).text("PowerApps");
    $(this).parent(".show-details").find('.show-me').fadeOut(500);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-details">
  <button class="btn btn-dark btnClick">PowerApps</button>
  <div class="show-me">
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h4>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-dark btnClick">Operational Efficiency</button>
  <button class="btn btn-dark btnClick">Together</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want? I didn't got it.

Comment: When I click the button "PowerApps", I want the h4 text to fade in and fade out if I click it again.

Comment: The current button text _is_ `PowerApps`, so this goes into the if-branch, where you are trying to fade-in the _already_ visible element. And since nothing changes the button text, it will still go into the if branch on the next clicks.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to include that the h4 element is of display:none so it is currently invisible? Should I make it so that the h4 element changes it's display class when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Use `fadeToggle()`, may be can solve your problem.